# jQuery carousel without cloning

Tags: jquery, charts, carousel

I'm using CanvasJS (http://canvasjs.com/) for charts on my site, but I want to put them in a carousel which turned out to be easier said than done.

I have tried a few different jQuery carousel plugins, but they all seem to have cloning in common, which I can't get to work with CanvasJS.

Basically the carousels I have found creates clones of the visible elements and place them outside the viewport to complete the loop. It clones all the canvas elements needed for CanvasJS, but not the actual charts which are only drawn on the original elements.

Is there any carousel plugins that doesn't use cloning, or is there another solution to make sliding CanvasJS charts work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BootStrap 3` has a Carousel that does not use cloning.

http://getbootstrap.com/

And an example of a carousel here:

http://bootply.com/99642

Comment: I was about to try out BootStrap anyways, so that's great to know. Thanks!